# Openfire Server XMPP setup on windows 7

Tags: android, localhost, xmpp, xmppframework

I want to build an Android application using XMPP protocol for sharing real-time data. For this, first of all, I have to setup XMPP Server and best server to use is Openfire. I tried to install this server on my Windows PC, but unable to setup correctly.

This is the download link https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/ from where I have downloaded the Openfire.exe file. After Installation it opens a browser window with URL=http://localhost:9090/ but the page shows "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. Search Google for localhost 9090 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue or suggest me the installation procedure? Also if you have any other suggestion to use another XMPP server kindly let me now. I want to transfer data in real-time from one Android device to another.

Thank you for reading my post and replying back.

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: My network had some firewall which blocked my port 9090, after disabling firewall for this port it works now.